# Jaws with aria-label

Tags: html, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader, section508

I have been working with on website where I need to use Jaws for vocals. Now issue is I have several `aria-label` available under one role. Now all I want is conditional speech i.e. when any control with `aria-label` is focused only that control's label should come as speech.

```
<ul id="ulOpenedTabs" role="tablist">
    <li *ngFor="let tab of activitytabs;  let i=index" role="tab" [attr.aria-selected]="tab.activity.IsSelected">
        <span>
            <span role="button" tabindex="0" title="Press to pinned" attr.aria-label="Press to pinned" attr.aria-pressed="false"></span>
        </span>
        <span>
           <span role="button" tabindex="0" attr.aria-label="Press enter to close menu"></span>
       </span>
    </li>
</ui>
```

Here as shown in HTML code there are two aria-label.As of now it takes both the label in the speech. And on change of focus it doesn't say anything. 
Now I want to have only one of the label in the speech which is currently focused.
Is it possible? And if yes then how?

Comment: Try different `tabindex=*`

Comment: Tried that. It stops working.

Comment: `role=navigation`

Comment: not working that as well

Comment: I don't follow your question. Are you saying when you tab to the first button it says  "press to pinned, press enter to close menu" or "press to pinned, press to pinned?" If it is the latter, it's because you have a `title`  and `aria-label` and probably verbose mode on.